# Can we get String value as a variable reference? (Variable Name)

Tags: java, swing

I have a string array like this,

```
String[] components = {"jButton1,jLabel1,jTextField1"};
```

I want to use this variable String names like this,

```
components[0].setText("Some Text");
```

Can I use String value as a variable name? this all variable declarations have in my code.

Comment: Why would you write `components[0].setText()` instead of `jButton1.setText()`?

Comment: You can, via reflection. But why not just store actual references to the components in the array?

Comment: Or a map. `map.put('jButton1', jButton1)`, then `map.get(buttonName).setText("Some text")`.

Comment: I think, he is trying to access `jButton` through a **variable variables** from `php` =). Right, @Sahan? In the `php` you can do following: `$name = 'someObj'; $$name->someMethod();`

Comment: Or umh, reference ID in components[] and then call findViewById()

Comment: Hello @kayaman I'm going to internationalize my java App. I get string keys from .properties file because I want to change language while running the program.

Comment: @Sahan Internationalization doesn't mean the translation of *variable* names!

Comment: @Sahan I would say it is better to do it the other way round: find the property which relates to `jButton1`, and then call `jButton1.setText(thePropertyValue)`.

Comment: @spirit this is what I want to get in PHP => `${'name'} = "test";`  `$name`

Comment: Here is the code I'm trying
`java.util.ResourceBundle bundle = java.util.ResourceBundle.getBundle("LANG/login_es_ES_EURO");
            Enumeration<String> keys = bundle.getKeys();
            
            while(keys.hasMoreElements()){
                String[] nameex = keys.nextElement().split("\\.",-1);;
                String vname = nameex[1];
                
                vname.setText(bundle.getString("logIn."+vname+".text"));
                
            }`

Answer (score 0):

While you do not need to change variable names while going for i18n, in order to get a variable name you could try this:

```
Class<?> myClass = this.getClass();
Field field = myClass.getField("fieldName");

if(field instanceof JButton)
    ((JButton)field).setText("My text");
```

Take a look at this tutorial, might help
http://omtlab.com/java-reflection-tutorial/

Comment: disagree with Reflection, there is (for example) get / putClientProperty